# Crystal Reporting From AX Database

Tags: crystal-reports, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am having an issue finding links within Crystal Reporting. I am trying to link 2 tables. However this seems to be a long task as I battle to find any links.

Is there a method that should be followed, as the most that have the same names to not link the tables correctly.

Comment: what is the issue? where to link tables in crystal reports? or how to link tables? be specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look on AX Data Dictionary Tables for the involved tables, then check the `Relations` node of the table. Any direct relation is usually on the *child* table. This of cause requires developer rights to the target AX system.

Remember to join on `DataAreaId` and `PartitionId` as well. Always check if any appropriate index exist.

Also the [Reverse Engineering Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc618797.aspx) may be of help.